# Use Ghostscript in for loop

Tags: batch-file, pdf, ghostscript

I need to merge hundred of pdf files into a new large one. In this code I try to loop through a file order list and add them into the new pdf file.
But the result is not what I need, because only the last pdf file in the loop get copied into the output.pdf. Whats wrong in my code?

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (fileorder.txt) do (
 echo +++++ %%A ++++++
 D:\GS\gs9.02\bin\gswin32c.exe ^
    -o output.pdf ^
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
    -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged ^
    -dEncodeColorImages=false ^
    -dEncodeGrayImages=false ^
    -dEncodeMonoImages=false ^
    output.pdf ^
    %%A ^
    -dFIXEDRESOLUTION
pause
)
```

Comment: Your code is not **adding/appending/merging** anything, it simply creates a new output file, always with the same name, for each input file. You need a command line like `gswin32c.exe ... file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf file4.pdf`, i.e. you execute `gswin32c` one time only with lots of files, not once for each file like you have.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The mistake is that when GhostScript gets called it clear the output.pdf and so the current %%A file get copied into a clear pdf file

Comment: @ZerOne: You know, the cmd console has an 8191 character limit for the length of a command.  If the combined length of all your PDF component filenames + the ghostscript command line switches exceeds that limit, the command will be truncated.  It'd be safer to use the [`@fileorder.txt` switch](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Use.htm#Switches) and let ghostscript get its file list from fileorder.txt.  That would also save you from having to figure out how to build your file list into a batch variable.

Comment: @rojo I found a solution by myself but your way is much better and easier. So thats the right answer!

Comment: @rojo maybe another question: how can I set the size of all pdfs to the same size?

Comment: `-sPAPERSIZE=letter` (or legal or a4 or whatever is appropriate).  If you have any other usage questions, [check the documentation](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Use.htm).  I've never messed with Ghostscript on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution by my own:
With this code I create a empty temp.pdf, which I need to save the output of the last loop to my input file.

```
copy NUL EmptyFile.txt
ren EmptyFile.txt temp.pdf
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (fileorder.txt) do (

D:\GS\gs9.02\bin\gswin32c.exe ^
-o output.pdf ^
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged ^
-dEncodeColorImages=false ^
-dEncodeGrayImages=false ^
-dEncodeMonoImages=false ^
temp.pdf ^
%%A ^
-dFIXEDRESOLUTION

copy /b/v/y output.pdf temp.pdf

) 

del temp.pdf
```

But as rojo pointed out: this is the better solution:

```
D:\GS\gs9.02\bin\gswin32c.exe ^
-o output.pdf ^
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged ^
-dEncodeColorImages=false ^
-dEncodeGrayImages=false ^
-dEncodeMonoImages=false ^
@fileorder.txt ^
-dFIXEDRESOLUTION
```